# Issue with installing R packages from github with devtools on university computers with network drives

Tags: r, github, devtools, reproducible-research

I'm trying to configure a project in R that uses the `spotifyr` and `scrobbler` (last.fm API) packages, but am having trouble when downloading from dev tools .

The code works perfectly from my Mac/Windows desktop at home, but when working on my work desktop (that’s mapped with network drives and protected by our University IT dept), I keep getting this for our packages work with the Spotify API and last.fm API, respectively.

> Error: Failed to install 'spotifyr' from GitHub:
>
> (converted from warning) installation of package
>   ‘C:/Users/NAME/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCO0e2Q/file26dc64eb83/spotifyr_2.1.1.tar.gz’
>   had non-zero exit status

and

> Error: Failed to install 'scrobbler' from GitHub:
>
> (converted from warning) installation of package
>   ‘C:/Users/NAME/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCO0e2Q/file26dc28aa3069/scrobbler_0.2.0.tar.gz’
>   had non-zero exit status

These packages are installed using devtools, and are installed from Github. Other packages downloaded from CRAN (R’s official package network) work fine.

I tried updating R, I have Rtools downloaded, and I have Git downloaded onto my work computer as well. I tried downloading the packages in zip files from Github and trying to install the packages locally using a different function in devtools but that did not work either.

I tried keeping the repository workspace both on a Network drive and on my local desktop, but had the same result. Not sure if this is something related to my university computer permissions or not.